# Namespacing in Laravel Views

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, laravel-5

I'm creating a "modular" Laravel app where related classes are grouped into their own directories and namespaces, which mirror the structure of the `app/` directory and `\App` namespace. A service provider registers views and defines routes for each module.

This structure works great to compartmentalize everything but a problem is in referencing controllers in views. In the main app module, to create a URL based off a controller action I can just use something like `{{ action('MyController@index') }}` because everything is relative to the `\App\Http\Controllers` namespace. In module views I have to do something like `{{ action('\Modules\MyModule\Http\Controllers\MyModuleController@index') }}` which works but is a lot to type and read, and something I need to replace every instance of if I ever rename a module.

Is there a way to make all views loaded as part of a module use the correct namespace? This is what is in the `boot()` function of my module service provider:

```
foreach($this->modules as $module) { // Module names in CamelCase
    $this->loadViewsFrom(base_path('modules/' . $module . '/Resources/Views'), strtolower($module));
}
```

which lets me reference views like `view('mymoduleinlowercase::folder.viewname')`

I can't seem to find any reference to the `loadViewsFrom()` function in the API documentation.

Comment: Would naming your routes and using `route('route.name')` be an option for you?

Comment: @lukasgeiter - I feel a little silly. Turns out it was already basically doing this. Will post an answer for anyone else who has this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So looks like it was already doing this basically automatically with named routes. The routing part of my `ModuleServiceProvider` class looks like this:

```
// $this->modules = ['Module1CamelCase', 'Module2CamelCase', ...];
foreach($this->modules as $module) {

    $routefile = base_path('modules\\' . $module . '\\Http\\routes.php');

    if(file_exists($routefile)) {

        $router->group(['namespace' => 'Modules\\' . $module . '\\Http\\Controllers', 'prefix' => strtolower($module)], function($router) use ($routefile) {
            require $routefile;
        });

    }
}
```

with `modules/MyModule/Http/routes.php` looking like:

```
$router->get('/', 'HomeController@index');
$router->resource('myresource', 'MyResourceController');
...
```

Because I used `'namespace' => 'Modules\\...` when specifying the options for the route group for each module, I can type `HomeController@index` in my `routes.php` file instead of `\Modules\MyModule\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index`.

I also used `'prefix' => 'mymodule'` in the options, so now I have nice named routes like `mymodule` for `HomeController@index` and `mymodule.myresource.show` for `MyResourceController@show`. To make a link to that I just use `{{ route('mymodule.myresource.show', $resourceid) }}` in a template file.

I didn't realize it was already naming my routes nicely for me automatically. It's easy to see though by running `php artisan routes:list` from the command line.